# Using \evaluate in nested \foreach loops with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to draw two grids side by side using TikZ; the left one being a complete square grid, and the right one being a lower-triangular one. I tried writing the following code to make the figure, but \yy is always equal to \y, and it only draws straight lines. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to draw the triangular grid?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Grid
    \draw[step=1,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    % Pads
    \draw (4.5,4.5) node {G};

    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \ystart using int(\x-6), evaluate=\x as \xx using int(\x+1)] in {6, 7,..., 10}
      \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using int(\y+1)] in {\ystart, ..., 4}
      \draw [color=gray] (\x,\y) rectangle (\xx,\yy) node {\y, \yy} ;
    % Pads
    \draw (10.5,4.5) node {G};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to enclose the content of the `\foreach` loop in curly braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Grid
    \draw[step=1,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    % Pads
    \draw (4.5,4.5) node {G};

    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \ystart using int(\x-6), evaluate=\x as \xx using int(\x+1)] in {6, 7,..., 10}{
      \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using int(\y+1)] in {\ystart, ..., 4}{
        \draw [color=gray] (\x,\y) rectangle (\xx,\yy) node {\y, \yy} ;
       }
    }
    % Pads
    \draw (10.5,4.5) node {G};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, I feel rather stupid for not trying this out.

Comment: That's odd behaviour.  I thought that for single-command `\foreach`s then there was no need to enclose like this.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: The braces are technically only required for the outer `\foreach`, the inner one works as expected.

Comment: But that's still not the *documented* (and therefore expected) behaviour.  I'm reading p504 of the manual and my interpretation is that this ought to have worked without the braces.  I'm clearly wrong in *practice* and I may be wrong in theory as well, but at least @arunchaganty shouldn't feel stupid for expecting it to work without the braces!